# IRB won't allow me to load my files?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am currently trying to create a program to solve the Mars Rover kata.

I can't load the file in IRB. Every time I try to load any of the files is says:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ./plateau
    from /Users/Emma01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Emma01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Emma01/projects/marsrover/lib/rover.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Emma01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Emma01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/Emma01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

My file structure is `rover`, `plateau` and `compass` and I tried various ways to require the file within the program. The Rover spec for examples has the following:

```
require 'plateau'

require 'rover'
```

Comment: Ruby doesn't include the current working directory in the load path by default. Have you tried `require_relative 'plateau'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `require` does not know about relative paths, use this tip for `require` in your scripts:

```
=> Dir['*.rb'] #<- show .rb scripts in this dir
=> ["foo.rb"]
=> require 'foo.rb'
#> LoadError: cannot load such file -- foo.rb #<- try load file
=> $: << '.' #<- add current dir to load path
=> require 'foo' #<- require you .rb script
=> true
```

Or use `require_relative` like @DylanMarkow said.

Comment: thanks, require_relative did not work but i shall this other approach!